# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',1,2,3' to data type int

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

This error results when attempting to use a comma delimited parameter in an IN condition

I'm passing a `varchar` parameter to a stored procedure that looks like this

```
,1,2,3
```

And I want to find out if it contains 1 (it doesn't always contain 1)

What's the easiest way to do that in TSQL ?

```
declare @Nums varchar(max)=',1,2,3'
if 1 in (@Nums) -- conversion error
BEGIN   
    select * from TestTable
END
```

Comment: There is no easy way to do it in TSQL. Strip all leading and trailing commas and then build a dynamic query that uses `in(1,2,3)`

Comment: I cant even figure out that much. I can strip the comma but how do I make a dynamic query that I can use in an IF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use LIKE to see if the string contains the character 1.  Note this will also match 12 or any string with the character '1' in it.

```
declare @Nums varchar(max)=',1,2,3'
if @Nums LIKE '%1%'
BEGIN   
    select * from TestTable
END
```

If you need to match the full number:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split_String]
(
    @ItemList NVARCHAR(4000), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @IDTable TABLE (Item VARCHAR(50))  
AS      

BEGIN    
    DECLARE @tempItemList NVARCHAR(4000)
    SET @tempItemList = @ItemList

    DECLARE @i INT    
    DECLARE @Item NVARCHAR(4000)

    SET @tempItemList = REPLACE (@tempItemList, ' ', '')
    SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)

    WHILE (LEN(@tempItemList) > 0)
    BEGIN
        IF @i = 0
            SET @Item = @tempItemList
        ELSE
            SET @Item = LEFT(@tempItemList, @i - 1)
        INSERT INTO @IDTable(Item) VALUES(@Item)
        IF @i = 0
            SET @tempItemList = ''
        ELSE
            SET @tempItemList = RIGHT(@tempItemList, LEN(@tempItemList) - @i)
        SET @i = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @tempItemList)
    END 
    RETURN
END


DECLARE @Nums VARCHAR(MAX) = ',1,2,3'

DECLARE @NumberTable TABLE (item INT)

INSERT INTO @NumberTable
  SELECT TRY_CAST(Item AS INT)
  FROM dbo.Split_String(@Nums, ',')

IF (SELECT 1 FROM @NumberTable WHERE item = 1) = 1
  BEGIN
    select * from TestTable
  END
```

Comment: *Note this will also match 12 or any string with the character '1' in it.* ...which makes this query not usable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CHARINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx).

```
declare @Nums varchar(max)=',1,2,3'
IF CHARINDEX(',1,', @Nums+',') > 0
BEGIN   
    select * from TestTable
END
```

Comment: I changed your answer a little but I think it works for any int now and is maybe what Will meant to say the first time

Comment: If you're just wanting to check if a character is in a parameter, this answer will work. If you're wanting to treat the parameter more like a set of data with comma delimiters, you're better off with something like Will described.